# Want to show Busy Loading message with percentage download when form will load using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

suppose my page content is huge so in my asp.net application i want to show busy icon with percentage downloading the content in client side. i saw many flash and sliver light site that they show busy icon and also they show percentage that means how much content has been loading in client machine. how could i achieve this using JQuery and when page content has been downloaded in client machine the busy icon goes out and actual page content will display.

please me with sample code to achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a placeholder image, and when the image you want is loaded, you could replace the placeholder with the new source

```
var img = new Image();
img.src= "largerImage.png";  
img.onload = function() { oldImage.src = img.src; };
```

This could be taken a step further, and the code could be added to the image itself

```
<img src="http://www.codedigest.com/img/loading.gif" 
 onload="var t = this; var img = new Image(); img.src ='http://hardgeek.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/firefox-logo-1024x969.jpg'; img.onload = function() { t.src = img.src }" />
```

Which could also be taken a step further, as you might not always have the ability to apply the onload directly like this, just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks for ur effeort....i think u guys do not understand what i was looking for.i want to show a message dialog when my page will be requested by user and in the message dialog it will show how much content of the page is downloading with percentage like 1% or 5%....so on. i am not looking for images preload etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like Uploadify. It does require a flash plugin. This is by far the easiest way.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Here is an example (ASP.NET MVC):

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/02/upload-files-with-progress-using-uploadify/

[Update] If you are trying to lazy load images, then use the jquery lazyload plugin. This only loads images that are in the current viewing area. As you scroll down, it fetches the next images. I use it on my blog page.

http://blog.bobcravens.com

View source and you will see (around line 13) a script that sets lazy loading on all post images.

Bob

Comment: thanks for ur effeort....i think u guys do not understand what i was looking for.i want to show a message dialog when my page will be requested by user and in the message dialog it will show how much content of the page is downloading with percentage like 1% or 5%....so on. i am not looking for images preload etc.